# mysql: searching BETWEEN dates stored as varchar

Tags: sql, mysql

i would like to `select * from table where dates between (some_date and another_date)`

the problem is that the dates are stored as `varchar`!

here are examples of dates that i have:

```
7/29/2010 9:53 AM
7/16/2010 7:57:39 AM
```

please notice that some records have seconds and some do not

i dont care about the time at all i just need the date

`reporttime` is the `date` field

this is not working:

```
SELECT * FROM batchinfo 
 where cast(reporttime as date) between ('7/28/10' and '7/29/10')
```

this:

```
SELECT * from batchinfo WHERE reporttime BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(7/28/2010, '%m/%/d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p')
                AND STR_TO_DATE(7/29/2010, '%m/%/d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p')
```

is returning:

```
Truncated incorrect datetime value: '7/8/2010 11:47 AM'
Incorrect datetime value: '0.00012009' for function str_to_date
```

this:

```
SELECT * from batchinfo WHERE STR_TO_DATE(reporttime, '%m/%/d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(7/28/2010, '%m/%/d/%Y')
                                                           AND STR_TO_DATE(7/29/2010, '%m/%/d/%Y')
```

is returning:

```
Incorrect datetime value: '7/8/2010 11:47 AM' for function str_to_date
```

OMG PONIES:

i am taking everything before the first blank:

```
SELECT * from batchinfo WHERE STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(reporttime,LOCATE(' ',reporttime)), '%m/%/d/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(7/28/2010, '%m/%/d/%Y')
                                                           AND STR_TO_DATE(7/29/2010, '%m/%/d/%Y')
```

and now i get this returned:

```
Incorrect datetime value: '7/8/2010' for function str_to_date
```

Comment: See my update - in the future, it'd help if you were more clear about what the issue was at the start.  Provide example data, table structure, and expected output.

Comment: The date format I provided was wrong. Should be '%m/%d/%Y'. Also when you put dates in your queries, put them in quotes '' (because they're in fact strings)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to search between dates, store them as dates. By storing them as strings you're shooting yourself in the foot. 
You'd basically need to extract date part from the string (using `SUBSTR()` or `LEFT()` ) and parse it to date format (using `STR_TO_DATE()`).

The performance of such solution will be appaling.

`STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(reporttime,LOCATE(' ',reporttime)),'%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2010-07-28' AND '2010-07-29'`

Comment: can you please show me what the select statement would look like

Comment: Incorrect datetime value: '7/8/2010 ' for function str_to_date

Comment: I ran into a similar situation.  I came to similar solution on my own, but it's good to see someone else doing it this way too as some confirmation.

Answer (score 8):

Use [STR_TO_DATE to convert the strings to the DateTime data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).  The format shorthand is found under [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
STR_TO_DATE(column, '%m/%/d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p')
```

The problem is, **you'll have to update the VARCHAR dates to all be the same format** ***first, before you can use***:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(reporttime, '%m/%/d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(some_date, '%m/%/d/%Y')
                                                           AND STR_TO_DATE(another_date, '%m/%/d/%Y')
```

Date formats are not consistent (some use hyphens, others slashes and Year/Month/day order can be totally different...), so STR_TO_DATE is the most accommodating & consistent means of turning a string into a DateTime.  Only after the value is DateTime, does Date/Time functionality become available like DATE() to get only the date portion...

Because of the data type change, an index on some_date & another_date columns can not be used.

Comment: reporttime is varchar, not date

Comment: @|__: I updated the WHERE clause in my answer - it wasn't clear to me what you're converting.  But mind that the data you listed is not consistently formatted.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: thank you again. ive updated the question using your updated answer

Comment: cant i just search through everything before the first blank, i dont care abotu the time

Comment: @|__: **mind that the data you listed is not consistently formatted**.  You have bad data - fix it first, the error is because the value is missing a seconds value.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: i am very sorry to trouble you, i am not just comparnig everything before the blank, and not including the time at all, please see updated q

Answer (score 1):

IF you are using SQl use this query

Data

```
DECLARE @Dates TABLE (StartDate varchar(100));

INSERT INTO @Dates VALUES ('7/1/2010 9:10 AM');
INSERT INTO @Dates VALUES ('7/5/2010 10:33 AM');
INSERT INTO @Dates VALUES ('7/13/2010 04:53 AM');
INSERT INTO @Dates VALUES ('7/22/2010 8:45 AM');
INSERT INTO @Dates VALUES ('7/10/2010 11:20 AM');
INSERT INTO @Dates VALUES ('7/11/2010 12:40 AM');
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM @Dates
WHERE (CONVERT(datetime,StartDate,101) >= CONVERT(datetime,'7/1/2010 9:10 AM',101))
                                         AND (CONVERT(datetime,StartDate,101) <= CONVERT(datetime,'7/15/2010 9:10 AM',101))
ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime,StartDate,101)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `CAST` your varchar values to DATETIME or DATE type.

```
WHERE CAST(dates AS DATE) BETWEEN (7/28/10 and 7/29/10)
```

This might not be an optimal solution, because you may lose the benefit that indexes provide.

Comment: SELECT * FROM batchinfo where cast(reporttime as date) between (7/29/10 and 7/28/10) - this does not work

Comment: Query: SELECT CAST('7/29/2010 9:53 AM' AS DATE); Result: Null

Comment: Not sure, but shouldn't 7/29/10 and 7/28/10 be reversed?

Comment: The problem is that the string data has to be in the default datetime format in order for CAST/CONVERT to work - need to use STR_TO_DATE if the format doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

This Date query will work perfectly...

```
Database 'Date' Will be like '01/01/2016' and datatype is 'varchar'

SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`test`.`date`, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31' ORDER BY `test`.`date` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If date is in Varchar

Query 
AND c.sentdate > '2016-jun-15'