# DB giving empty result set when fetching the data between two dates of different months

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm working with php/mysql.when i'm trying to fetch the data between two dates everything working fine.but when i want to fetch the data between two months for example: 31-01-2014 and 03-02-2014 its not working and giving the empty result set.its workign fien withing a month.

Here is my query :

```
$sql1="select
        reg.id, 
        payonline.regno as FORM_NO,
        payonline.paydate as DATE,


        reg.stufname as FIRSTNAME,
        reg.stumname as MIDDLENAME,
        reg.stulname as LASTNAME,
        reg.stuemail as EMAIL,
        DATE_FORMAT(reg.studob,'%d-%m-%Y') as DOB,
        reg.stugender as GENDER,
        reg.stumobile as MOBILE,

        prg.paymentmode as PAYMENTMODE,
        prg.examdate as TESTDATE,
        prg.examcenter as EXAM_CENTER,
        prg.hostel as HOSTEL,
        prg.coursetype as PRG_TYPE,
        prg.campus1 as CAMPUS1,
        prg.course1 as PRG_NAME1,
        prg.campus2 as CAMPUS2,
        prg.course2 as PRG_NAME2,
        prg.pgd_intrested as pgd_intrested,
        prg.pgd_course1 as pgd_course1,
        prg.pgd_campus1 as pgd_campus1,
        prg.pgd_course2 as pgd_course2,
        prg.pgd_campus2 as pgd_campus2,
        family.stufname as FATHERNAME,
        family.stufoccupation as FATHER_OCCUPATION,
        family.stufmobile as FATHER_MOBILE,
        family.stufspecify as FATHER_SPECIFY,
        family.stufincome as FATHER_INCOME,
        family.stufemail as FATHER_EMAIL,
        family.stumname as MOTHERNAME,
        family.stumoccupation as MOTHER_OCCUPATION,
        family.stummobile as MOTHER_MOBILE,
        family.stumspecify as MOTHER_SPECIFY,
        family.stumincome as MOTHER_INCOME,
        family.stumemail as MOTHER_EMAIL,
        family.guardianname as GUARDIAN,
        family.guardianaddress as GUARDIAN_ADDRESS,
        family.guardianphone as GUARDIAN_PHONE,
        address.presentaddress as PRESENT_ADDRESS,
        address.presentcity as PRESENT_CITY,
        address.presentstate as PRESENT_STATE,
        address.presentpin as PRESENT_PIN,
        address.presentcountry as PRESENT_COUNTRY,
        address.presentphone as PRESENT_PHONE,  
        address.permanentaddress as PERMANENT_ADDRESS,
        address.permanentcity as PERMANENT_CITY,
        address.permanentstate as PERMANENT_STATE,
        address.permanentpin as PERMANENT_PIN,
        address.permanentcountry as PERMANENT_COUNTY,
        address.permanentphone as PERMANENT_PHONE,
        address.mailingaddress as MAILING_ADDRESS,

        edu.10_streamname as 10_STREAM,
        edu.10_institutename as 10_INSTITUTE,
        edu.10_year as 10_YEAR,
        edu.10_board as 10_BOARD,
        edu.10_percentage as 10_PERCENTAGE,
        edu.10_subjects as 10_SUBJECTS,

        edu.12_streamname as 12_STREAM,
        edu.12_institutename as 12_INSTITUTE,
        edu.12_year as 12_YEAR,
        edu.12_board as 12_BOARD,
        edu.12_percentage as 12_PERCENTAGE,
        edu.12_subjects as 12_SUBJECTS,

        edu.g_streamname as G_STREAM,
        edu.g_institutename as G_INSTITUTE,
        edu.g_year as G_YEAR,
        edu.g_university as G_UNIVERSITY,
        edu.g_percentage as G_PERCENTAGE,
        edu.g_subjects as G_SUBJECTS,

        edu.pg_streamname as PG_STREAM,
        edu.pg_institutename as PG_INSTITUTE,
        edu.pg_year as PG_YEAR,
        edu.pg_university as PG_UNIVERSITY,
        edu.pg_percentage as PG_PERCENTAGE,
        edu.pg_subjects as PG_SUBJECTS,

        edu.m_streamname as M_STREAM,
        edu.m_institutename as M_Institute,
        edu.m_year as M_YEAR,
        edu.m_university as M_UNIVERSITY,
        edu.m_percentage as M_PERCENTAGE,
        edu.m_subjects as M_SUBJECTS,

        ext.stuexamcenter as EXAMCENTER,
        ext.activities as ACTIVITES,
        ext.awards as AWARDS,
        ext.options as OPTIONS,
        ext.mat as MAT_YEAR,
        ext.matscore as MAT_SCORE,
        ext.cat as CAT_YEAR,
        ext.catscore as CAT_SCORE,
        ext.gmat as GMAT_YEAR,
        ext.gmatscore as GMAT_SCORE,

        work.job1 as JOB1,
        work.org1 as ORG1,
        work.designation1 as DESIGNATION1,
        work.sdate1 as START_DATE1,
        work.edate1 as END_DATE1,

        work.job2 as JOB2,
        work.org2 as ORG2,
        work.designation2 as DESIGNATION2,
        work.sdate2 as START_DATE2,
        work.edate2 as END_DATE2,

        work.job3 as JOB3,
        work.org3 as ORG3,
        work.designation3 as DESIGNATION3,
        work.sdate3 as START_DATE3,
        work.edate3 as END_DATE3,

        dd.ddno as DD_NO,
        dd.dddate as DD_DATE,
        dd.ddbank as DD_BANK,

        payonline.receiptno as RECEIPT_NO,
        payonline.txnno as TRANSACTION_NO,

        payonline.status as STATUS,
        payonline.amount as AMOUNT

         from  registration as reg
         join programme as prg on reg.id=prg.stuid              
         join family on reg.id=family.stuid         
         join address on reg.id=address.stuid 
         join education as edu on reg.id=edu.stuid
         join extradetail as ext on reg.id=ext.stuid
         join workexperience as work on reg.id=work.stuid
         join demanddraft as dd on reg.id=dd.stuid
         join payonline on reg.id=payonline.stuid where payonline.status='success' and payonline.paydate >= '".$_POST['date1']."' and payonline.paydate <= '".$_POST['date2']."'";
```

Comment: What are the types of your `paydate` fields?

Comment: And maybe you could reduce this problem to a simpler case for clarity, so that it doesn't have the kitchen sink in the select list?

Comment: Also, please consider the sql injection vulnerability you have in your example. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @Chris Farmer : its varchar

Comment: I suggest you deal with real date types if you expect to be able to compare them as dates. You could use `str_to_date` to convert your varchars to dates during the query, but that's likely to be really slow for a table of any meaningful size.

Comment: @ Chris Farmer: i have convert them at later stage bro

Comment: @Chris Farmer :everything working fine for me dear the problem occurs only when i m going to one month to another for example : 31-01-2014 and 03-02-2014

Comment: As Alireza Amiri says in his answer, the reason it *appears* to work for dates within the same month is because you're just getting lucky that the string comparisons "work" within the same month. If your fields were proper date types, you would be able to successfully compare *any* dates. Another low-rent "solution" to this problem would be to choose a different string format for your dates -- one that would allow alphabetic comparisons, such as yyyy-MM-dd.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best solution is **to save date in DATE or DATETIME or Timestamp format.**

But in your case, As said in [THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3471204/2613728) , you can convert them to DATETIME in your query using [STR_TO_DATE](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php) and [LEFT](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-left-function.php) in your conditions:

STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(payonline.paydate,LOCATE(' ',payonline.paydate)),'%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2010-07-28' AND '2010-07-29'

Comment: everything working fine for me dear the problem occurs only when i m going to one month to another for example : 31-01-2014 and 03-02-2014

Comment: The same month works, because the dates in the same month can be compared as strings, but in other cases you will have problem!!! So for dealing with dates without any worry, you should use the correct format, as I said :)