# Mysqli fetch data using between Query in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to get data form table using mysqli "Between" function. But it gives me wrong result i want to get data form "01-03-2017" to "30-03-2017". My database have only 2 values one is "21-03-2017" another is "22-03-2017". But my query return me 6 values including "February". I want only march values.

This is my Table (Id="INT", Name= "Varchar", Date="Varchar")

```
id  | name  | date 
--------------------
1   | name1 | 01-02-2017
2   | name1 | 02-02-2017
3   | name1 | 03-02-2017
4   | name1 | 04-02-2017
5   | name1 | 05-02-2017
6   | name1 | 06-02-2017
7   | name1 | 07-02-2017
8   | name1 | 21-03-2017
9   | name1 | 22-03-2017
```

This is MYSQLI Query

```
SELECT * FROM `booking` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '01-03-2017' AND '30-03-2017'
```

Check here result. It gives me wrong reustl. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfdBf.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql: searching BETWEEN dates stored as varchar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471094/mysql-searching-between-dates-stored-as-varchar)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `booking` WHERE CAST(`date` AS DATE) BETWEEN '01-03-2017' AND '30-03-2017'
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM `booking` WHERE CAST(`date` AS DATE) BETWEEN '2017-03-01' AND '2017-03-30'` You are type casting here.