# I have date stored as varchar in mysql database with format like that 07/17/2017

Tags: mysql

I have stored datetime as varchar unfortunetly i have lot of data comes in , now i want to get records between two dates below is my query but it is not returning the correct result set

```
$start_date=$_POST['start_date']; 
    $to_date   =$_POST['end_date'];
     $wbs =$_POST['wbs'];
     if(!empty($_POST['wbs'])) 
     {
   $query="SELECT * FROM plan_voucher WHERE location=".$_SESSION['role']." and created_at between '".$start_date."' and '".$to_date."'";
```

Comment: This may be better suited to the psychic forum - but if using varchar dates then probably best not to bother with an RDBMS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql: searching BETWEEN dates stored as varchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471094/mysql-searching-between-dates-stored-as-varchar)

Comment: Convert your improperly stored text dates using `STR_TO_DATE`, something like this: `STR_TO_DATE(date_col, '%m/%d/%Y')`.  _Don't_ store your dates as text!

Answer (score 0):

use date conversion that already said @Tim in his comments and try your query like below way

```
SELECT * FROM plan_voucher WHERE location=".$_SESSION['role']."
and STR_TO_DATE(created_at,'%m/%d/%Y') between '".$start_date."' 
and '".$to_date."'";
```

Comment: i echo the query and it returns "SELECT * FROM plan_voucher WHERE location=1 and STR_TO_DATE(created_at,'%m/%d/%Y') between '07/13/2017' and '08/09/2018'

Comment: yap run it on your dbms